# SQLAlchemy Imperatively Mapping a Composite Entity without __composite_values__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'd like to use SQLAlchemy to build my relational schema, but due to project constraints, the central model should not have any dependencies on any third-parties, and I'd like to avoid adding a `__composite_values__` method to any class that could be used as a composite in the database.

As a concrete example, suppose I have the following entities:

```py
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Transaction:
    id: int
    value: Money
    description: str
    timestamp: datetime.datetime

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Money:
    amount: int
    currency: str
```

Of course, when I attempt to create an imperative mapping using these classes, I get `AttributeError: 'Money' object has no attribute '__composite_values__'`:

```py
transaction_table = Table(
    "transaction",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column("description", String(1024)),
    Column(
        "timestamp",
        DateTime(timezone=False),
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("NOW()"),
    ),
    Column("value_amount", Integer(), nullable=False),
    Column("value_currency", String(5), nullable=False),
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Transaction,
    transaction_table,
    properties={
        "value": composite(
            Money,
            transaction_table.c.value_amount,
            transaction_table.c.value_currency,
        )
    },
)
```

So, what are my options for mapping these classes? So far, I've only been able to think of the solution where I create a duplicate wrapper for each entity which *does* have the ORM-specific attachments, but this seems quite nasty.

Answer (score 1):

How about subclassing `Money` ?

```
class DbMoney(Money):
  def __composite_keys__(self):
    return self.amount, self.currency

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Transaction,
    transaction_table,
    properties={
        "value": composite(
            DbMoney,
            transaction_table.c.value_amount,
            transaction_table.c.value_currency,
        )
    },
)
```

Alternatively, you can also monkey patch your `Money` class. It sounds ugly but this is what SQLAlchemy does anyway.

```
def get_money_composite_values(self):
    return self.amount, self.currency

setattr(Money, "__composite_values__", get_money_composite_values)
```

In my (limited) experience, the later is a bit more usable later on (no need to instanciate the subclass).